# Jackson 2.0 Afterburner issues with missing node

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm having some issues hooking up the Afterburner module for Jackson. The issue can best be summarized by the test case below. Apologies for the lengthy example; I've tried to keep it as short as possible for this exercise. The test works when you comment out the line that registers the module and fails when you leave it in.

I'm using Jackson 2.1.1 for annotations, core and afterburner.

I'd appreciate any ideas you might have.

Thanks!

Caps

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.AfterburnerModule;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

public class AfterburnerTest {

    @Test
    public void mapOccupancyNoMaxAdults() throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new AfterburnerModule());

        final JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(
                "{" +
                    "\"max\":3," +
                    "\"adults\": {" +
                        "\"min\":1" +
                    "}," +
                    "\"children\":{" +
                        "\"min\":1," +
                        "\"max\":2" +
                    "}" +
                "}");

        final Occupancy occupancy = objectMapper.reader(Occupancy.class).readValue(node);

        assertNull(occupancy.getAdults().getMax());
        assertNotNull(occupancy.getChildren().getMax());


    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Occupancy {

        private Integer max;
        private Guests adults;
        private Guests children;

        public Occupancy() {
        }

        public Occupancy(Integer max, Guests adults, Guests children) {
            this.max = max;
            this.adults = adults;
            this.children = children;
        }

        public Integer getMax() {
            return max;
        }

        public Guests getAdults() {
            return adults;
        }

        public Guests getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Guests {

        private Integer min;
        private Integer max;

        public Guests() {
        }

        public Guests(Integer min, Integer max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public Integer getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public Integer getMax() {
            return max;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this test passes with Jackson 2.2.0 and Afterburner module. Perhaps underlying issue you hit has been since resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I can try to see what error you get, but one thing worth noting is that Afterburner will typically not help speed of Tree Model based access too much. Why? Because those do not use Reflection-based getter/setter access, so there isn't much to optimize.

In your sample code there should be some speedup for second part (converting from Tree Model to POJO), as that does go through regular access. Just not for the first part.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem which I solved like this:

> new AfterburnerModule().setUseOptimizedBeanDeserializer(false)

The problem is that, maybe because of this, I see no performance improvement with Afterburner...